# Android - alert dialog - self made cancel button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

I have updated the alert dialog box format using my own layout xml.

In this customerized alert dialog box there are 2 buttons, one button is to save the data being input, another one is a cancel button.

How could I write for the CANCEL button such that when the user click it, just simply to DISMISS the dialog box?

```
   public OnClickListener NewRowButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {               
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
          builder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_add, null));
          builder.create();

          AlertDialog Custom_dialog_add = builder.create();
          Custom_dialog_add.show(); // show the Dialog

          Button CancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);
          CancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
              @Override 
              public void onClick(View v) {Custom_dialog_add.cancel();}  //WRONG: Cannot refer to a non-final variable Custom_dialog_add inside an inner class defined in a different method
            });         
      } 
   };
```

it is now revised as follows:

```
       public OnClickListener NewRowButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
       { 
          @Override 
          public void onClick(View v)  
          { 
              AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 
              dialog.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_add, null)); 
              dialog.create(); 

               final AlertDialog test = dialog.create(); 
               test.show();

               Button close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CancelButton); 
               close.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() { 
                   public void onClick(View v) { 
                       test.dismiss(); 
                   } 
               });
          }
       };
```

The Eclipse does not report bugs to the revised codings, but when simulated, it runs out a nullpointer exception. The logcat is as follows. How could such be solved?

```
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at com.pearappx.gamescore3.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:422)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
09-28 20:15:19.505: E/AndroidRuntime(25847):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: just make Custom_dialog_add final and see it again

Comment: it is still not ok, the program becomes run time error 
09-27 02:09:25.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 02:09:25.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12350): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 02:09:25.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12350):com.pearappx.gamescore3.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:397)
09-27 02:09:25.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12350):android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
09-27 02:09:25.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12350):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
09-27 02:09:25.330: E/AndroidRuntime

Comment: its better if you post the entire logcat if the problem isnt solved yet.
(post your logcat in your question)

Comment: The code is pointed out by Eclispse that it is wrong, where the Custom_dialog_add.cancel();} this part, Eclispse say that it cannot refer to a non-final variable Custom_dialog_add inside an inner class defined in a different method. The program still unable to run after that~and hence not yet have Lotcat

Comment: Once give a try to this one LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) cont
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
builder.setView(li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_add, null));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this code snippet help you?

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("dialog");
        dialog.setView(view);
        final AlertDialog test = dialog.create();


        Button close = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.close_button);
        close.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                test.dismiss();

            }
        });
```

**Edit updated version:**

```
    //Create new alert dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //set title
    dialog.setTitle("title");
    //create the dialog in a final context
    final AlertDialog test = dialog.create();
    //inflate the custom layout in to a View object
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_add, null);

    //find the Button object within the inflated view
    //                       ↓↓↓
    Button close = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);
    //set the onClickListener
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            test.dismiss(); 
        } 
    });
    //show the dialog
    test.show();
```

Don't forget to use the right imports!

Comment: how to define for the "test" for the last code: test.dismiss() ??

Comment: Test needs to be final, to be accessed in this way. I m'n not sure what you mean but if you make your AlertDialog a global variable and implement the onClickListener interface in the same class, you will be able to access the AlertDialog too.

Comment: In other words, because AlertDialog test is final you can call the test.dismiss() without a problem.

Comment: thanks for your code and i have tried, but it highlighted for 2 "contexts" in the above. both says that it has context cannot be resolved...

Comment: Oops my fault, change context to "this" or if your working within a fragment to "getActivity()". I also updated the above code!

Comment: the dialog can now be properly inflated, if, without the Button close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);  part, the logcat reports line 422 close.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener()  that contributes to a nullpointer exception, what is that? sorry for asking such questions...i am really just start learning coding..i have posted the revised codes and the logcat as in the above question..thanks! and i have modified the original inflating part as the "this" also reports error by Eclipse, while the current one doesn't report any, but i dont know if this would affect

Comment: Updated code again, what your missing in your new code in the question is that you inflate the view and set directly using setView. And Than you are trying to find the button within the context of your own activity. But your activity does not have a button and that is causing a null exception. so the findViewById call needs to be done on the View object like this: view.findViewById (See my update code with comments)

Comment: Officially this comment section is not for discussions but i like to say: patience is the only way you will learn programming.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a seperate activity to lauch the layout as a dialog or any other way?
If you are using seperate activity to lauch the layout

simply call

```
youractivity.this.finish()
```

in your cancel button onclick event

Comment: it is within the same activity. just because i have tailor-made for the alert dialog, there are no more positivebutton and negative button anymore? (i dont know if i am correct or not). i just simply want to know how to dismiss the dialog when pressing the cancel button? many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here an example:

```
 // creates Dialogs for this Activity
   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
       final Dialog dialog;
       switch(id) {
       case DIALOG_REALLY_EXIT_ID:
           dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(
                               "Do you really want to exit this activity?")
           .setTitle("Exit activity")                    
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //add your code you would like to be execute when clicking "yes"
                //for example the below to exit your activity
                    //Main.this.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No",
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel(); //to dismiss this dialog
           //add any additional things you would like to execute when pressing the no button

               }
           }).create();
           break;
       default:
           dialog = null;
       }
       return dialog;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This inside the dialog { } (ex: public void Dialog(...){ here.. }

```
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener cancel = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            1 add = 1.this;
            add.finish();

            Intent showActivity = new Intent(1.this, 2.class);
            1.this.startActivity(showActivity);

        }
    };
```

Edit these:
1 - name of the .java file you're at.
2 - name of the .java class you want to open/show when Dialog canceled.

Then put this code

`builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", cancel);`

What will happen?
when you click in the "Cancel" button it will close the "page(with dialog) and will open the activity/page you want.

---

or try this: `dialogo.setNeutralButton("Cancel", null);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the button by yourself. Set an onClickListener over that button and inside onClick() you can call `dialog.cancel();` which simply cancels the dialog.